# Spark - how to append new columns to an original dataframe after split?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to split a column of a DataFrame (`col3`) into multiple columns (`col_a`, `col_b`, `col_c`). And to substitute the single column with the multiple columns.

```
+---------------------------------+
|col1|col2| col3  |col4|col5|col6 |
|   a|   b| a,b,c | d  |  n | r   | 
|   d|   e| f,f,f | p  |  b | null|
+---------------------------------+
```

So I split the column in the following way:

```
val new_DF = original_DF.withColumn("_tmp", split($"col3", "\\,")).select(
  $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col_a"),
  $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col_b"),
  $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("col_c")
).drop("_tmp")
```

But `new_DF` contains only of the new three columns. How can I make the new columns a part of the original `original_DF` without `col3`?

**UPD:** I've managed to achieve the desired result but it doesn't look pretty at all. Will be grateful for any suggestions on how to improve this approach.

```
val new_DF = original_DF
  .withColumn("col_a", split($"col3", "\\,").getItem(0))
  .withColumn("col_b", split($"col3", "\\,").getItem(1))
  .withColumn("col_c", split($"col3", "\\,").getItem(2))
  .drop("col3")
```

Answer (score 2):

Without duplications:

```
val withArrayColumn = original_DF.withColumn("col3Array", split($"col3", ","))
val columnNames = Seq("a", "b", "c").zipWithIndex
val result = columnNames
  .foldLeft(withArrayColumn)((updated, columnIndex) => updated.withColumn("col_" + columnIndex._1, $"col3Array".getItem(columnIndex._2)))
  .drop("col3Array", "col3")
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick :

```
val new_DF = original_DF.withColumn("_tmp", split($"col3", "\\,")).select(
  $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col_a"),
  $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col_b"),
  $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("col_c"),
  original_DF.columns.filter(_ != "col3"): _*)
)
```

Selecting all columns from `original_df` without `col3`

Answer (score 1):

It is a small improvement

```
val new_DF = original_DF.select(col("col_1"),
          col("col_2"),
          col("col3").getItem(0).as("col_a"),
          col("col3").getItem(1).as("col_b"),
          col("col3").getItem(2).as("col_c"),
          col("col_4"),
          col("col_5"),
          col("col_6"))
```